# Injective map of $R$-modules with $R$ containing the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have the following doubt:

Let   $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a morphism of $R$-modules where all the elements of $\ker(f)$ are annihilated by $p$. ($R$ is a ring that contains the integers.)

Now if $M$ has an element $z$ which is annihilated by $q$, where $p$ and $q$ are coprime, I consider $T$ the submodule generated by $z$.

How can I see that the composition
$$T\rightarrow M \rightarrow N$$

is injective?

If I take one element in the kernel of that composition, that element is in the kernel of $f$. Thus I have one element that is annihilated by $p$ and $q$.

Does it follows from the fact that

$$1\cdot z= (pt +ql)z=0\ ?$$

Comment: could you please make your notation a little clearer, what is $x$ and $l$, what are you assuming about $R$, is it noetherian?

Comment: Yes, it does...